# Using Parallel Block Workflow to send email notifications

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, email-notification

How does SharePoint react to workflows that run parallel with pauses? will the following work?

[image]

I have a List that is for tracking and reporting of contracts, and I need some notifications near the end of the contract. I was going to use the IM Policy to start workflows at specific dates and the workflows were just send an email. the problem with that is IM Policy triggers in sequential stages, and the notification dates I'm using are not always in a a set order. This list will have around 2K active items at any given time so I'm trying to stay away from having a complicated workflow always in progress on each. So my thought is to use the IM policy to trigger a workflow that looks like the one above. will this work? is there a better solution I'm not aware of?
Thanks

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT number 2

So I take the part below, copy it for each notification date, and use the IM policy to run every week until the next stage which is a final end date. will this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not work. The workflow would pause until the latest day and then send three emails together at that day.

Workaround, you could create three workflows instead. Then use the IM Policy to trigeer the three worflows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: that was my first thought, but the IM Policy triggers in a sequential order. the dates I want it to trigger are not always in the same order. I've edited my workflow (posted above) but it doesn't seem to be responding like I thought. there is no history for some reason and it says completed.

Comment: The workflow would not work too. You have too compare the three dates, the logic would be like this: pause untill the smallest date, send an email. Then pause until the second date, send an email. Pause until the biggest date, send an email. If you have three date column, it should have 6 situations. I have updated my answer for your reference.

Comment: wow, that's excellent. a thought did occur to me though, what if I used one workflow, like my edit above, with the parallel emails. and use the IM Policy to trigger it every week until the next stage triggers. then for each notification date it would be if "end_date" is greater than today - 7 and less than or equal to today, send email. this means I wouldn't have duplicate emails, and the workflow would run then complete, so I wouldn't getting hanging workflows. then the next stage will trigger from a date of my choosing and the first stage would stop running? does this makes sense?

Comment: If you use the IM policy to trigger the workflow everyweek, this shuold work for you. But the email may not be sent on that date. It may send the email 7 days before the date.

Comment: that's ok, these are end of contract notifications and if they are a week late, that's fine. if my date range is the last 7 days, and the IM policy runs on the weekend. everyone will get notifications from the last week on the monday. thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: You could accept my answer if it helps you:)